# Centering a section with text inside a container

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a height: 246px, I then have a div with text inside which I want to center vertically and horizontally in the div and also in this container.

The desired result should look like this [Navy row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p080T.png)

My code currently looks like this:

html

```
<section id="rowsec">
        <div class="colwrap">
                <span class="layer">41%</span>
                <span class="stat">Company average cost saving  versus originator brands on the South African market</span>
                <span class="layer">10+</span>
                <span class="stat">Company has 10 market leading brands within the family of products</span>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
#rowsec {
height: 246px;
width: 100%;
 background-color: #0c225f;
}
/* Clears floats after the columns */
#rowsec:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
.colwrap{
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
}

.layer {
font-family: 'HKGroteskMedium';
font-size: 75px;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 1.2;
color: #9fb8ff;
}

.stat {
padding-left: 35px;
font-weight: 500;
font-style: normal;
font-stretch: normal;
line-height: 1.45;
color: #ffffff;
max-width: 412px;
}

.colwrap a{
float: left;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x15v5znr/ check it out thats fits your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display:flex` to `#rowsec` and `vertical-align:middle` to `span`

```css
#rowsec {
  height: 246px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0c225f;
  display:flex;
}
span{

vertical-align:middle;}

/* Clears floats after the columns */

#rowsec:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.colwrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.layer {
  font-family: 'HKGroteskMedium';
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #9fb8ff;
}

.stat {
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.45;
  color: #ffffff;
  max-width: 412px;
}

.colwrap a {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="rowsec">
  <div class="colwrap">
    <span class="layer">41%</span>
    <span class="stat">Company average cost saving  versus originator brands on the South African market</span>
    <span class="layer">10+</span>
    <span class="stat">Company has 10 market leading brands within the family of products</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The problem I encountered with using this, was that my column width for {.stat} no longer worked. But display:flex seems to do the trick! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Cathy ,if it helped then please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

just modify the css of `#rowsec` and `.colwrap`

```css
#rowsec {
    height: 246px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0c225f;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
/* Clears floats after the columns */
#rowsec:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
.colwrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.layer {
font-family: 'HKGroteskMedium';
font-size: 75px;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 1.2;
color: #9fb8ff;
}

.stat {
padding-left: 35px;
font-weight: 500;
font-style: normal;
font-stretch: normal;
line-height: 1.45;
color: #ffffff;
max-width: 412px;
}

.colwrap a{
float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="rowsec">
        <div class="colwrap">
                <a class="layer">41%</a>
                <a class="stat">Company average cost saving  versus originator brands on the South African market</a>
                <a class="layer">10+</a>
                <a class="stat">Company has 10 market leading brands within the family of products</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fo9vuwdb/)

Comment: if answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. :)

Comment: Thanks so much it worked perfectly!

Comment: can you please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you? @Cathy